# Direct command to set EV3 motor speed

Tags: ev3, programming

I am trying to set a EV3 motor's speed and start it remotely using a direct command. Using the resources [LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Communication Developer Kit](https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt6879b00ae6951482/LEGO_MINDSTORMS_EV3_Communication_Developer_Kit.pdf) (page 24) and [LEGO MINDSTORMS EV3 Firmware Developer Kit](https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt77bd61c3ac436ea3/LEGO_MINDSTORMS_EV3_Firmware_Developer_Kit.pdf) (page 53) I've came up with the following (Kotlin) code to create the command:

```
ByteBuffer
    .allocate(18)
    .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .putShort(16)
    .putShort(0)
    .put(0x80.toByte())
    .putShort(0)
    .put(0xA5.toByte())
    .put(0)
    .put(0b01)
    .put(leftSpeed.toByte())
    .put(0xA5.toByte())
    .put(0)
    .put(0b10)
    .put(rightSpeed.toByte())
    .put(0xA6.toByte())
    .put(0)
    .put(0b11)
```

However, the EV3 behaves really unpredictably, with some speed values (the range is -100 to 100) flipping the polarity, some even crashing the OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters must be encoded. See section 4.2 in the *Communication Developer Kit* and section 3.4 in the *Firmware Developer Kit*.

Here are the referenced macros from `bytecodes.h`:

```
//        MACROS FOR PRIMITIVES AND SYSTEM CALLS

#define   PRIMPAR_SHORT                 0x00
#define   PRIMPAR_LONG                  0x80

#define   PRIMPAR_CONST                 0x00
#define   PRIMPAR_VARIABLE              0x40
#define   PRIMPAR_LOCAL                 0x00
#define   PRIMPAR_GLOBAL                0x20
#define   PRIMPAR_HANDLE                0x10
#define   PRIMPAR_ADDR                  0x08

#define   PRIMPAR_INDEX                 0x1F
#define   PRIMPAR_CONST_SIGN            0x20
#define   PRIMPAR_VALUE                 0x3F

#define   PRIMPAR_BYTES                 0x07

#define   PRIMPAR_STRING_OLD            0
#define   PRIMPAR_1_BYTE                1
#define   PRIMPAR_2_BYTES               2
#define   PRIMPAR_4_BYTES               3
#define   PRIMPAR_STRING                4

#define   PRIMPAR_LABEL                 0x20

#define   HND(x)                        (PRIMPAR_HANDLE | (x))
#define   ADR(x)                        (PRIMPAR_ADDR | (x))

#define   LCS                           (PRIMPAR_LONG | PRIMPAR_STRING)

#define   LAB1(v)                       (PRIMPAR_LONG | PRIMPAR_LABEL),((v) & 0xFF)

#define   LC0(v)                        (((v) & PRIMPAR_VALUE) | PRIMPAR_SHORT | PRIMPAR_CONST)
#define   LC1(v)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_CONST | PRIMPAR_1_BYTE),((v) & 0xFF)
#define   LC2(v)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_CONST | PRIMPAR_2_BYTES),((v) & 0xFF),(((v) >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define   LC4(v)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_CONST | PRIMPAR_4_BYTES),((ULONG)(v) & 0xFF),(((ULONG)(v) >> (ULONG)8) & 0xFF),(((ULONG)(v) >> (ULONG)16) & 0xFF),(((ULONG)(v) >> (ULONG)24) & 0xFF)

#define   LV0(i)                        (((i) & PRIMPAR_INDEX) | PRIMPAR_SHORT | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_LOCAL)
#define   LV1(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_LOCAL | PRIMPAR_1_BYTE),((i) & 0xFF)
#define   LV2(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_LOCAL | PRIMPAR_2_BYTES),((i) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define   LV4(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_LOCAL | PRIMPAR_4_BYTES),((i) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 8) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 16) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 24) & 0xFF)

#define   GV0(i)                        (((i) & PRIMPAR_INDEX) | PRIMPAR_SHORT | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_GLOBAL)
#define   GV1(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_GLOBAL | PRIMPAR_1_BYTE),((i) & 0xFF)
#define   GV2(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_GLOBAL | PRIMPAR_2_BYTES),((i) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define   GV4(i)                        (PRIMPAR_LONG  | PRIMPAR_VARIABLE | PRIMPAR_GLOBAL | PRIMPAR_4_BYTES),((i) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 8) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 16) & 0xFF),(((i) >> 24) & 0xFF)
```

Values withing the range 0 to 31 can essentially be passed directly since `PRIMPAR_SHORT` and `PRIMPAR_CONST` used in `LC0()` are both 0 (values -31 to -1 can also be used as LC0 but need to be bitwise and-ed with 0x3F). But since the speeds can be +/-100, they need `LC1()` which requires two bytes.

So something like this?

```
ByteBuffer
    .allocate(20)
    .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
    .putShort(18) // command size
    .putShort(0) // message counter
    .put(0x80.toByte()) // direct command, no reply
    .putShort(0) // globals/locals
    .put(0xA5.toByte()) // opOutput_Speed
    .put(0) // LAYER=LC0(0)
    .put(0b01) // NOS=LC0(1)
    .put(0x81).put(leftSpeed.toByte()) // SPEED=LC1(leftSpeed)
    .put(0xA5.toByte()) // opOutput_Speed
    .put(0) // LAYER=LC0(0)
    .put(0b10) // NOS=LC0(2)
    .put(0x81).put(rightSpeed.toByte()) // SPEED=LC1(rightSpeed)
    .put(0xA6.toByte()) // opOutput_Start
    .put(0) // LAYER=LC0(0)
    .put(0b11) // NOS=LC0(3)
```

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate your response. I am not familiar with the encoding, did I get this right? For each argument, if its range (signed) is within +/- 31 I should pass it through the LC0 macro, if it's +/- 127 I should pass it through the LC1 macro and so on? and that means that the encoded speed is actually 2 bytes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.